# Solving a recurrence using the Master Theorem

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms

I have the following recurrence relation, which I'm trying to solve using the Master Theorem:

T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n(2 + sin(n))

I compared this recurrence to the one of the following form:

T(n) = aT(n/b) + f(n)

Where a = 2, b = 2 and f(n) = n(2 + sin(n))

$n^{log_ba} = n^{log_22} = n$

Comparing f(n) and $n^{log_ba}$ asymptotically:

f(n) = n(2 + sin(n))

$n^{log_ba} = n$

Now this is the part where I am stuck. The dominating term in f(n) is n (as -1 <= sin(n) <= 1), which is the same as $n^{log_ba} = n$. Would this imply that this recurrence satisfies the second case of the Master Theorem?

The second case is:
If $f(n) = Θ(n^{log_ba})$, then $T(n) = Θ(n^{log_ba}logn)$

Comment: Since $\sin(n)\in O(1)$, then yes you get $O(n\log n)$.

Comment: Just to clarify, what does it mean to say that sin()∈(1) ?

Comment: It means $\sin n$ is bounded by a constant, which in this case is $1$.

Comment: @neoni The point is that you can write $f\in \Theta(n)$ by taking into account the $\sin$ bound. I recommend checking the relevant chapters in Cormen's book. It will help you both with regards to asymptotic growth notions, usage of the Master theorem, and finding growth of recurrences even where the Master theorem doesn't work. I also recommend checking out Akra-Bazzi.